# How to populate a List with a while loop without declaring a new object every time?

Tags: java, arrays, list, while-loop

So, I'm trying to s a list of documents that contain a term and then enter the corresponding document_id and the term frequency into an array (of size 2). I then add this entry array into a List, so that the final List contains an all the entries. However, because the entry is passed by reference into the List, I have no idea how to accomplish this, since it rewrites itself every time. And due to the size of the data, my program runs out of memory if I try to declare a new int[] entry within the while loop. Any ideas on how to get pass this? I'm a but rusty on my Java. Thanks.

```
List<int[]> occurenceIndex = new ArrayList<>();
int[] entry = new int[2];  

while (matchedDocs.next())
{
    entry[0] = (matchedDocs.doc());    // Adds document id 
    entry[1] = (matchedDocs.freq());   // Adds term weight
    occurenceIndex.add(entry);
}
```

Comment: What is the size of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `HashMap` to store records.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> occurenceIdx = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
while(matchedDocs.next())
    occurenceIdx.put(matchedDocs.doc(), matchedDocs.freq());
```

That's all the code you need to create the map. To retrieve value based on doc ID

```
docFreq = occurenceIdx.get(docId);
```

Please note that this will work ONLY if you have unique doc IDs. If not, you will have to improvise on this solution. I would probably make my map a `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>` to support multiple instances of docID

Comment: how about if he has dupplicate docId's ? and the order of the list ?

Comment: I'll mention it as a note in my answer.

Comment: Moreover, the OP doesn't mention anything about the order of the list, so I am not sure that it is a constraint.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! The document IDs are indeed unique, and the order doesn't matter, as long as I can retrieve them.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a new object of the int array inside the loop.

```
List<int[]> occurenceIndex = new ArrayList<>();
while (matchedDocs.next())
{
   int[] entry = new int[2];
   entry[0] = (matchedDocs.doc());    // Adds document id 
   entry[1] = (matchedDocs.freq());   // Adds term weight
   occurenceIndex.add(entry);
}
```

Comment: `And due to the size of the data, my program runs out of memory if I try to declare a new int[] entry within the while loop`

Comment: You can use a Map<Integer, Integer> and add docs to it. Assuming the id is unique. If even this fails then assign more memory.

Comment: the op needs to check whether the Map solution is suitable for him

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `int[] entry = new int[2];` into the while loop

does it need to be an int, what about byte or short? if this isn't possible then the program needs to be re-factored as there is no way to store the arrays like this using the same array instance. – Neil Locketz 1 min ago edit

Comment: `And due to the size of the data, my program runs out of memory if I try to declare a new int[] entry within the while loop`

Comment: does it need to be an int, what about byte or short? if this isn't possible then the program needs to be re-factored as there is no way to store the arrays like this using the same array instance.

Comment: the OP needs to answer that. I agree that there is no way to store the arrays without using a new object per iteration